# How does the electric field of one particle affect another?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Im curious as how exactly a Electric field physically applies a force to positive/ negative charges within its field. What interaction takes place? Does a charge simply “touch” the field and experiences a force at the point of contact?

I am having a hard time conceptually understanding this and one way I have heard this explained from an [MIT EM course](https://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/guidedtour/Tour.htm) (Section C ‘most specifically) is seeing the electric field as “lines of force” and are in “tension” along the field lines(attraction b/w opposite charges) and apply “lateral pressure” transverse to the field lines (repulsion b/w like charges)

I can accept the field lines contracting/being in tension to explain attraction except for the fact that for the lines to reach another charge (or combine with another line if you will) they would have to radiate outwards or “stretch” to that charge.

You can say “oh thats easy! Thats like an elastic band or spring!” Except when you boil down where those internal forces come from, they are explained to be electromagnetic in nature. And they are electromagnetic in nature because those forces come from attraction/repulsion of charges, which, is what we are trying to define…

I hope this makes sense what im asking.
I would really appreciate any help in visualizing this concept, it has caused me a lot of frustration… cheers!

Edit: if classic EM fails to explain this, i would like to hear if QED explains this better i would like to hear those explanations as well!

Comment: There is no explanation to this in classical electrostatics. In quantum mechanics, there might be an explanation.

Comment: Jake : Can I get your email ID or whatsapp number? All questions you asked on this site are interesting

Comment: Related: [How does an electric field apply force to charged particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732946/how-does-an-electric-field-apply-force-to-charged-particles)

Comment: *Thats like an elastic band or spring.* Why do you think electromagnetism should be understandable in terms of the objects that you dealt with in Newtonian mechanics? It’s a different subject, and a more beautiful and fundamental one. EM (together with QM) explains elastic bands and springs, not the other way around.

Comment: @Ghoster I agree thats what I am struggling with. The idea of Springs/elastic band seems more intuitive because the model of it would explain how the “lines of force” get to the charge (a spring stretching out) and then the “lines of force” causing attraction (spring returning back)

Comment: There is no reason to expect physics to be “intuitive”. Most students don’t even find Newtonian mechanics to be intuitive; their intuition leads them to think more like Aristotle did. The most fundamental physics is the *least* intuitive, which is why it has taken centuries since the beginning of science to discover.

Comment: Duplicate: [How does an electric field apply force to charged particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732946/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does an electric field apply force to charged particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732946/)

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Charges and relative motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651969/charges-and-relative-motion/652210#652210). **(2)** [Trajectory of electric field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667475/trajectory-of-electric-field-lines/668506#668506). **(3)** [Fields of a moving electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352620/fields-of-a-moving-electron/382859#382859). **(4)** [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/electric-field-associated-with-moving-charge).

Comment: @Frobenius wow thank you for those related posts! I can tell you have a profound understanding and had put a lot of detail into those posts…and yes those duplicates were my questions…i’ve struggled to fully grasp this concept for a bit now..

Comment: Welcome to PSE....and Happy New Year.

Comment: @Frobenius thank you and happy new year!

Comment: @lorilori I do not have a WhatsApp and  make it a point not to share my personal email online (personal choice). If you feel comfortable leaving your email I would be happy to write you so we can correspond

Comment: @Jake : christianoronaldo1700@gmail.com

Comment: As long as we are not curious about the components and structure of the electric field, the magnetic field and the EM quanta, your question cannot be answered.